# Active Directory - Verifying the access token

Tags: java, azure, active-directory, postman, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to integrate Microsoft Azure Active directory in my application,
Here's what I have able to achieve so far and where I am stuck -

1.
My URI to request an Authorization code -

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant-id}}/oauth2/authorize?
response_type=code%20id_token
&scope=openid
&response_mode=query
&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8081/dashboard.html
&client_id={{client-id}}
&nonce={{nonce}}
&site_id={{site_id}}
```

I have been able Authenticate the user and successfully redirect the authenticated user to the redirect_uri page,
My Front end received 3 things from AD after successful redirection -

```
a) id_token
b) code
c) session_state
```

2.
Using these I am able to successfully ake a post call to the Microsoft endpoint, to receive Access tokens, following are the call details -

```
Endpoint - https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant-id-here}}/oauth2/token
Type - Post
Headers - Content-Type
Body(application/x-www-form-urlencoded) - grant_type, code, client_id, redirect_uri, client_secret, resource
```

3.
Microsoft endpoint responds with following data -

```
a) token_type
b) expires_in
c) ext_expires_in
d) expires_on
e) access_token
f) refresh_token
g) id_token
```

4.
Now as per the OAuth process, my Front end passes the access_token on every API call, this access_token is supposed to be verified by hitting some Microsoft endpoint, which I believe is the following one -

```
Endpoint - https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages
Type - Get
Header - Authorization
Header value - Bearer {{Access-token}}
Parameters - client_id
```

**Error message -** 
This request if failing with 404

[image]

**Can someone help me understand -** 
1. Am I hitting the correct endpoint to verify the access_token?
2. If yes what a I doing wrong?
3. If no, which is the correct endpoint? and what should be it's request details?

Here are my reference docs - 
1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code 
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code

**Tried hitting the following endpoint as well -**

```
Endpoint - login.microsoftonline.com/{{tenant-id}}/oauth2/authorize
Type - Post
Header - Authorization, Content-Type
Header value for Authorization- Bearer {{Access-token}}
Header value for Content-Type- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Body(application/x-www-form-urlencoded) - client_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the resource parameter.

Even though it is said to be optional, it is included in every sample here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code.

So when you retrieve the tokens from `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/token`, remember to include the `resource` parameter, and set its value to `https://graph.microsoft.com` to get tokens to use on Microsoft Graph API.

I can also say that in your screenshot you are not passing the access token in the header. That looks like an authorization code or refresh token. You must pass the access token.

Comment: As suggested I added resource with it's value "https://graph.microsoft.com", The access_token I received this time looks like a JWT, I passed it to the graph API, this time I get a 404 :'(

Comment: Well, that's not unauthorised :) What URL are you trying to access?

Comment: I'm making a get call to graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?client_id=myClientId , with Header Authorization, Header value for Authorization- Bearer {{Access-token}} , Should my resource be service.contoso.com instead of https://graph.microsoft.com ?

Comment: You should not need the client id parameter. The header should look like: `Authorization: Bearer eydadakddsadas...`. And no, the resource has to be `https://graph.microsoft.com`. It's the Application ID URI that AAD generates nowadays for new apps. That URL is the Graph API's ID URI.

Comment: I've updated the image in my question, still 404, unable to figure out where I'm going wrong, I did set resource as https://graph.microsoft.com while calling the token api, although I do have our Application Id, should I use that?

Comment: That is really puzzling though. Is your tenant an Office 365 tenant? Since you are trying to access emails?

Comment: I am not sure, I received the tenant id from our client, But I am not trying to access emails, I just want to validate the access_token.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146279/discussion-between-aniruddha-raje-and-juunas).